Is it a problem that the indoor unit of a mini-split AC/heat pump is not properly leveled?
I noticed that the indoor component of my new mini-split installed by the handymen today is not properly leveled. It's off by about 0.3 inch (0.75 cm). I believe that would amount to a 0.5 degree angle at the length of my AC which is about 2.75 ft (85 cm). I wondered if this will damage the AC over time. Will there be any issues with condensation, drainage, noise or efficacy, or with the refrigerant itself?

@isherwood so I've measured it, and it is about 0.3 inch (0.75 cm) difference from the farthest left side to the farthest right. That I believe turns out to be a 0.5 degree angle at the 2.75 feet (around 85 cm) length of my indoor unit.
So yeah, you are right, 2-3 degrees would be a lot, however even this is pretty noticeable, you can't miss it.

Cool. Update your question, though.

The refrigerant is under pressure, so it doesn't care. The big concern is condensate, which all air conditioners produce - and the hotter/more humid the air, the more condensate there will be. You should have a tube or pipe somewhere that drains condensate. If that is working correctly then you're fine. If it isn't then you could end up with a big mess.

The drain hoses are on the left side. The AC angles from the left to the right side, so does that mean that it pools to the other side of the drain?

That's what it sounds like. But whether 3 degrees matters is another story - that might not be an issue at all. Do you get much coming out of the drain hoses?
